# Display polynomials in reverse order in SageMath

Tags: latex, polynomial-math, sage, display

So I would like to print polynomials in one variable (`s`) with one parameter (`a`), say

`a·s^3 − s^2 - a^2·s − a + 1`.

Sage always displays it with decreasing degree, and I would like to get something like

`1 - a  - a^2·s - s^2 + a·s^3`

to export it to `LaTeX`. I can't figure out how to do this... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to string manipulation, one can use the series expansion.

```
F = a*s^3 - s^2 - a^2*s - a + 1
F.series(s, F.degree(s)+1)
```

returns

```
(-a + 1) + (-a^2)*s + (-1)*s^2 + (a)*s^3
```

which appears to be what you wanted, save for some redundant parentheses.

This works because (a) a power series is ordered from lowest to highest coefficients; (b) making the order of remainder greater than the degree of the polynomial ensures that the series is just the polynomial itself.

Comment: This seems to work very well for the purpose of exporting it to `LaTeX`, adding minor tweeks for the parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

This is not easy, because the sort order is defined in Pynac, a fork of Ginac, which Sage uses for its basic symbolic manipulation.  However, depending on what you need, it is possible programmatically:

```
sage: F = 1 + x + x^2
sage: "+".join(map(str,sorted([f for f in F.operands()],key=lambda exp:exp.degree(x))))
'1+x+x^2'
```

I don't know whether this sort of thing is powerful enough for your needs, though.  You may have to traverse the "expression tree" quite a bit but at least your sort of example seems to work.

```
sage: F = a + a^2*x + x^2 - a*x^2
sage: "+".join(map(str,sorted([f for f in F.operands()],key=lambda exp:exp.degree(x))))
'a+a^2*x+-a*x^2+x^2'
```

Doing this in a short statement requires a number of Python tricks like this, which are *very* well worth learning if you are going to use Sage (or Numpy, or pandas, or ...) a fair amount.

Comment: Really good info. This works very well as you say, but it turns out that exporting it to `LaTeX` doesn't work so well, being strings.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking about the LaTeX, good point!  Though one could fairly easily do so by using `map(latex` instead of `map(str`, probably.

Comment: Yes thanks, that works better for the export, but still it inserts some newlines in the form of `\\`. Both solutions are really handy and helpful for what I needed.